# Springboot-why i cannot set url localhost:8080/helloworld to get text "hello world"?

Tags: java, spring-boot

What i built, is just a very simple springboot project, only one class for application, and one class for controller.

I just want, everytime when people visit "localhost:8080/helloworld"
The text "Hello World!" should be shown.

However, i got an error "APPLICATION FAILED TO START", please see the screenshots and the error message.

If i just delete this controller.java, it will be compile fine. So the problem must be the controller.java

Does any one knows, what is wrong? Thank you!

Part1: myApplication.java

```
package com.zi.sbprojects;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ApiApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

Part2:myController.java

```
package com.zi.sbprojects.helloworld;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ControllerHelloWorld {

    @RequestMapping("/helloworld")
    public String sayHelloWorld() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

}
```

Part3: pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.zi.sbprojects</groupId>
  <artifactId>sb-firstproject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>My First Spring Boot Project</name>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

</project>
```

part4: Error Message

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.0.RELEASE)

2019-06-09 18:25:03.150  INFO 7148 --- [           main] com.zi.sbprojects.ApiApp                 : Starting ApiApp on N0474010 with PID 7148 (started by SangZi in C:\Spring Tools\sb-firstproject)
2019-06-09 18:25:03.155  INFO 7148 --- [           main] com.zi.sbprojects.ApiApp                 : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-06-09 18:25:05.887  INFO 7148 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-06-09 18:25:05.916  INFO 7148 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-06-09 18:25:05.916  INFO 7148 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.12
2019-06-09 18:25:05.930  INFO 7148 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_92/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_92/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_92/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\BMC Software\ARSystem\dataimporttool;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin;C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.3-bin\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin;C:\Users\sangzi\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\sangzi\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\sangzi\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2019.1.2\bin;;C:\Users\sangzi\Downloads\spring-tool-suite-3.9.8.RELEASE-e4.11.0-win32-x86_64\sts-bundle\sts-3.9.8.RELEASE;;.]
2019-06-09 18:25:06.073  INFO 7148 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-06-09 18:25:06.073  INFO 7148 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2815 ms
2019-06-09 18:25:06.116  INFO 7148 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2019-06-09 18:25:06.131  INFO 7148 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2019-06-09 18:25:06.132  INFO 7148 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2019-06-09 18:25:06.140  INFO 7148 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'formContentFilter' to: [/*]
2019-06-09 18:25:06.141  INFO 7148 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2019-06-09 18:25:06.477  INFO 7148 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-06-09 18:25:06.804 ERROR 7148 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase   : Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:960) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:259) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:197) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:300) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) [spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.zi.sbprojects.ApiApp.main(ApiApp.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:236) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1108) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:550) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:957) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    ... 14 common frames omitted

2019-06-09 18:25:06.812  INFO 7148 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-06-09 18:25:06.834  INFO 7148 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-06-09 18:25:06.837 ERROR 7148 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen on another port.

2019-06-09 18:25:06.841  INFO 7148 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
```

This error has everything you need. You already have an application running on the same port as your spring boot application.

### Steps to Troubleshoot.

On OSX, you can run the following command:

```
lsof -i :8080
```

This will give you a list of the processes that are currently running that are bound to port `8080`.

Comment: On Windows, run `netstat -ano | findstr 8080`. Last value is the process ID.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to just click on the red button to terminate the running progress, and press the green button run, it worked..

Comment: But thank you so much for the trouble shooting method!

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, please accept it. The other answer is also satisfactory, to choose either one :)

Answer (score 1):

I provide below few lines, it may be helpful to you.

As per the above exception message,

> Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
>       at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
>       at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]

It means, the port 8080 which is default in spring boot has been occupied. It means another application is running in the same port 8080. To solve this problem, you can refer one of the below following approaches.

1. You can configure `server.port=8090` in application.properties file in spring boot application. You can mention port number based upon the convenience.
2. Configure only `-Dserver.port=8090` in VM arguments in eclipse or intellij Idea
3. If you have spring boot fat jar, you can run using the command `java -jar springboot.jar --server.port=8090`. I have given the name as springboot.jar, you can have your own name for spring boot application.

Answer (score 1):

All answers above are good. One more reason: It may be that you already started your application once, dind't stop it, changed something and tried to start it again. Check if there are Java processes running and, if you see your previously started application, kill it.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things that I note.

1. Your address is already in use.

Solution:

Change the port by specifying it in the `application.properties` as `server.port=8081` or any other free ports or stop the current process as christopher mentioned.

2. You are returning String from the controller method.

If you want the page to display `Hello world` on the browser then use `@ResponseBody` for the method.

Answer (score 0):

I am also creates same stuff as he did , my project console also look fine.

but still my application is not running on localhost:8080/hello

Comment: How does this answer the question?